# How to account for the No Data values assigned to a raster data? It is creating error while doing Logistic Regression in TerrSet

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, terrset, logistic-regression

I am trying to perform a logistic regression using the LogisticReg function in TerrSet. I have one dependent variable the pixel values in which are 0 and 1. But when I am trying to import this raster layer in TerrSet it says only 0 and 1 values allowed (since there are no data values in the background which are not 0 or 1). If I assign a specific value (e.g. -9999) to the no data region it creates further confusion in analyzing the data as it takes them into consideration while doing the calculation and the descriptive stat as well as coefficients change. What should I do? Is 'ignore nodata values' an option?

Comment: It's not ArcGIS which is assigning random values unless you asked it to, in which case it seems unfair to imply data corruption in the title. If your otherwise 1-bit data has legitimate NODATA values, then you might not be able to use a utility which expects Boolean, not ternary data.